# Printing solution for PHP web app

Tags: php, networking, printing, barcode

We're developing a web application (written in PHP) for a company and they have remote branches with a decent connectivity to the internet. I'm looking for a solution to allow the remote branch to:

1. Print receipts using a thermal printer
2. Print label for package using a barcode printer

Is there a single hardware solution that can do the 2 functions? Since the web app doesn't have any concept of a locally-attached printer, is it possible to send the data over the network and to the printer? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP isn't really the right platform to talk to printers. Why don't you write a desktop application in a language with better OS API hooks (C/C++/C#/VB/Java/etc) that makes an HTTP/TCP request over the network to the PHP app, whose response tells it whatever it needs to print. The local app at the branch does the printing.

Comment: That can be an alternative. I have to look for another set of developers for this though. I'm also trying to limit the number of technologies that need to be in the ecosystem. The less apps to maintain, the better.